# MDX: Drillthough not filtering out rows

Tags: excel, ssas, mdx, olap

I have a drillthrough that I am building where I want to filter on two members of the same hierarchy:

```
    DRILLTHROUGH MAXROWS 1000 SELECT FROM 
(
  SELECT (
  { [Product].[Product Exclusion Reason].[Product Exclusion Reason].&[6],[Product].[Product Exclusion Reason].[Product Exclusion Reason].&[1] } ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Sales]
 )
 WHERE ([Fiscal Date].[Yr-Qtr-Mo].[Year].&[2013])
```

The sub-select does not seem to filter these rows out. If I instead add a critieria to the where clause:

```
 DRILLTHROUGH MAXROWS 1000 SELECT FROM 
(
  SELECT (
  { [Product].[Product Exclusion Reason].[Product Exclusion Reason].&[6],[Product].[Product Exclusion Reason].[Product Exclusion Reason].&[1] } ) ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Sales]
 )
 WHERE ([Fiscal Date].[Yr-Qtr-Mo].[Year].&[2013],
```

[Product].[Product Exclusion Reason].[Product Exclusion Reason].&[1])

This will filter the data as expected. However, I want to include multiple members of `[Product].[Product Exclusion Reason].[Product Exclusion Reason]` in my filtering.

Comment: Have you tried to delete your Where clause and create a more complex subcube? Do you create the mdx query runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a query like this one?

```
DRILLTHROUGH MAXROWS 1000
  SELECT { [Fiscal Date].[Yr-Qtr-Mo].[Year].&[2013] } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Sales]
  WHERE { [Product].[Product Exclusion Reason].[Product Exclusion Reason].&[6],[Product].[Product Exclusion Reason].[Product Exclusion Reason].&[1] }
```